# Generating Two Random Variables Between 0 and 1 Using Same Formula

Tags: c++

I'm trying to generate two different random variables between 0 and 1 at the start of my main function. I need the two variables for use in comparing different possible outcomes. However, when I try to run the formula twice it says 'redefinition of gen' error. Can someone please advise on how to resolve this error so I can re-use the same formula and store the values into two different variables.

```
  random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
    auto value = dis(gen);
    cout << "r value is " << value << endl;

  random_device sd;
    mt19937 gen(sd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
    auto c = dis(gen);
    cout << "c value is " << c << endl;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rename your second generator `gen2` (same for `dis2`):

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
auto value = dis(gen);
cout << "r value is " << value << endl;

random_device sd;
mt19937 gen2(sd());
uniform_real_distribution<> dis2(0, 1);
auto c = dis2(gen2);
cout << "c value is " << c << endl;}
```

Comment: Ah ok. I thought I needed to use the same name 'gen' for the generator portion.

Comment: Or move the generator into its own function that can be called over and over as needed.

Comment: I think I also need to rename dis to dis2 (or some other name)

Comment: @user3753931 correct, changed answer accordingly

Comment: Remy - can you elaborate on your comment. I think I somewhat get what your saying, but an example would be helpful

Comment: Similar to my comment above: if I implement this random variable generation code in my main() function and then want to use value and c in other method definitions that I call later in main. Can you advise on how would I implement that?  Would I make a function with a parameter equal to this random variable generated and then pass that parameter to my other method definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You may reuse the distribution and generator:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
auto value = dis(gen);
auto c = dis(gen);
```

Comment: Ok - so if I run your code in my main() function, but want value and c to be globally accessible to all methods I've created how would I proceed?

Comment: `dis(gen)` generates a new random number. `value` and `c` may be declared global if you want.

Comment: Sorry - so I have implemented your code Jarod42 in my main() function. But, I want to then use value and c in other method definitions that I call later in main. Can you advise on how would I implement that?  Would I make a function with a parameter equal to this random variable generated and then pass that parameter to my other method definitions?

Comment: Hi Jarod, Thanks. I figured out how to fix what I had issues with, I'd upvote your response but I don't have 15 reputation yet

Comment: You may pass the value directly to sub-function or use global (see https://ideone.com/oAnSFP).